# Is there a way to check if a div, contains an img, and then use that as a conditional on an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I know this question probably sounds very similar to many other questions, but I've tried quite a few of the other solutions to similar questions and they do not seem to be working. Maybe I'm just explaining it poorly, but I have tried a lot.

Basically, I want to move images to different divs, based on whether or not a div already contains an image.

I've already tried multiple different ways of checking to see if the div with specific id contains an img .has(), .contains(), etc. and no dice. I'm not sure if it's just the syntax that's an issue or what.

HTML

```
    <div id="imgsDiv">
        <img src="assets/images/peas.jpeg" id="peas" class="imgStyles" alt="peas">
        <img src="assets/images/broccoli.jpeg" id="broccoli" class="imgStyles" alt="broccoli">
    </div> 

<div id="playerDiv">
        </div>

        <div id="computerDiv">
        </div>
```

jQuery/JS

```
$(".imgStyles").click(function (event) {
    if ($("#playerDiv:contains('img')")) {
        $(event.currentTarget).appendTo("#computerDiv");
        console.log("sucess");
    } else {
        $(event.currentTarget).appendTo("#playerDiv"); 
    }
})
```

Basically, I want to be able to click on any image and have the first image go to the #playerDiv, and then every other image that gets clicked after that go to #computerDiv. Right now, all the images just append themselves to #computerDiv even though #playerDiv starts with no images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**.length**](https://api.jquery.com/length/)
<sup>The number of elements in the jQuery object</sup>

- `if ($("#playerDiv").find("img").length)` means if there is any img in the div .. It will return true if the div contains any img ..
- Also `if ($("#playerDiv").find("img").length > 0)` same as previous one .`0` here is the number of elements
- Try to `console.log($("#playerDiv").find("img").length)` and you'll got the point ..
- `if ($("#playerDiv").has("img"))` should work also BUT while you said *and have the first image go to the #playerDiv* so you can use `if ($("#playerDiv").find("img").length == 1)`

```js
$(".imgStyles").on('click' , function (event) {
    if ($("#playerDiv").find('img').length == 1) {
        $(this).appendTo("#computerDiv");
        console.log("To computerDiv");
    } else {
        $(this).appendTo("#playerDiv");
        console.log("To playerDiv");
    }
})
```

```css
#playerDiv{
  background : red;
}
#computerDiv{
  background : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imgsDiv">
<img src="assets/images/peas.jpeg" id="peas" class="imgStyles" alt="peas">
<img src="assets/images/broccoli.jpeg" id="broccoli" class="imgStyles" alt="broccoli">
<img src="assets/images/peas.jpeg" id="peas" class="imgStyles" alt="peas">
<img src="assets/images/broccoli.jpeg" id="broccoli" class="imgStyles" alt="broccoli">

</div> 

<div id="playerDiv"></div>

<div id="computerDiv"></div>
```

- AND about using [**.contains**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) <sup>Select all elements that contain the specified text.</sup> .. So it isn't work for element it works for text

**Finally:** If you need to prevent the appended images from append again you can do this by add a class to the appended image and use `:not` selector

```js
$(document).on('click' , ".imgStyles:not(.appended)" ,function (event) {
    if ($("#playerDiv").find('img').length == 1) {
        $(this).addClass('appended').appendTo("#computerDiv");
        console.log("To computerDiv");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('appended').appendTo("#playerDiv");
        console.log("To playerDiv");
    }
})
```

```css
#playerDiv{
  background : red;
}
#computerDiv{
  background : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imgsDiv">
<img src="assets/images/peas.jpeg" id="peas" class="imgStyles" alt="peas">
<img src="assets/images/broccoli.jpeg" id="broccoli" class="imgStyles" alt="broccoli">
<img src="assets/images/peas.jpeg" id="peas" class="imgStyles" alt="peas">
<img src="assets/images/broccoli.jpeg" id="broccoli" class="imgStyles" alt="broccoli">

</div> 

<div id="playerDiv"></div>

<div id="computerDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Why is length needed here though?

Comment: @Zamurph Another ways like `.has` only check for if any number of elements inside the jquery object and return `true/false` ..BUT while in your case needs to check if the `playerDiv` has one `img` so you'll need to check the `length` the number of `img`s .. So `.length` let you make that